# Why nagios check_users result not equal linux "who -q"

Tags: linux, nagios, devops

**Why nagios check_users result not equal linux "who -q"?**

Below sample:

The "who -q" result is **66**, but the check_users result is **91**.

```
$ who -q
wjlu ltwu ltwu tyqiu tyqiu wjlu kunli clchen wjlu wjlu snzhao ltwu ltwu jianzhang wjlu wwwu snzhao qyhan nwei hcheng clchen wjlu wjlu qyhan dmli jyu dmli wjcai wjlu kunli tyqiu tyqiu snzhao wjcai jianzhang wwwu wjlu qyhan snzhao snzhao wwwu wwwu qyhan wwwu nwei fye jyu gqzhu clchen gqzhu yfeng snzhao yfeng yfeng qyhan qyhan wwwu yfsun fjchen ltwu bjwang qyhan qyhan wjcai fjchen wjlu
# users=66
$
$ /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_users -w 85 -c 105
USERS WARNING - 91 users currently logged in |users=91;85;105;0
$
```

I looked the source code check_users.c (line 280)

```
if (sscanf (input_buffer, _("# users=%d"), &users) == 1)
```

It seems it read from "who -q" result.
I was confused why the results is not same.

Comment: From the "who -q" result, you can see there are many duplicate login user, such as ltwu, tyqiu
so should have other reason.

Comment: oops, missed that. Well, don't know what to say. Good luck!

Comment: just to make it clearer for other readers, maybe you want to edit output so it's easier to read. `who -q | sed 's/ /\n/g' | sort | uniq -c`. To bad `check_users` doesn't make a list. Is there an option to list them? Just guessing. I don't think I'll have much more to add on this, so Good Luck!

Comment: Are you running these two commands from the same user account?

Answer (score 1):

The 'who' command output is only used by check_users **if** your system does not have UTMP support.  Nearly all *nix machines have this, if you can 'ls /var/log/utmp' and see a file by that name, then your machine has it.  UTMP and 'who' have slightly different definitions as to what is a 'user process' and 'user login', therefore, they will not *always* output the same values.

For example: UTMP  will often count individual terminal windows on the *console* as separate logins - even though they belong to a single user; while 'who' only lists the console login itself as a single (or possibly 2) logins.

There are also some configurations that disallow certain users from 'seeing' other user logins, so either of these ran from an account other than 'root', may not generate accurate numbers.

Just noticed that console screen locking can throw off these numbers as well.  Should a console user still be considered as being 'logged in' if their screen is locked?  Guess that's a debate for another day.